# bootstrap: how to make an alert take the width of its content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make an alert take the width of its content?

This div will take all the available space while I would like it to be only as long as my text.

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <span class="glyphicon icon-info"></span> My text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this..

```
.alert {display:inline-block;}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/124763

Note, that this approach will change behaviour of all alerts. If you don't need it, you can add class:

```
.alert-auto {display:inline-block;}
```

and use it only where you need auto-width alert.

Comment: is there a way to not change the behaviour of all alerts? add a new class?

Comment: Sure you can do `.alert-auto {display:inline-block;}` and then add `alert-auto` to the alert's class attribute

Comment: ok so Boostrap set up ``dislay:inline`` for the alerts. I guess there might be a reason why they did not use ``inline-block``.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it as below

```
<div class="alert alert-success" style="display:inline-block;"> Your Content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  .alert {display:inline-block;}
```

put on your .css to make the inline alert fit to your text